# Play Framework 2.5.4 Async Hibernate operations

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.5

How can you use Akka to perform an operation on the db using Hibernate and not block the web client?

**UPDATE:**

Turns out the error was caused by the dao.get() method. I changed the start() method to take an actual object and not the id from the database and now I get no error, but nothing is happening(it gets stuck on em.merge() as I previously said).

```
public CompletionStage<Result> start(SomeObject object) {
    ExecutionContext ec = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("akka.actor.db-context");
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doStuff(object), play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecution.fromThread(ec))
            .thenApply(i -> ok("Got result: " + i));
}
```

---

**OUTDATED:**

If I try something like:

```
@Transactional
public CompletionStage<Result> start(Long id) {
    ExecutionContext ec = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("akka.actor.db-context");
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doStuff(dao.get(id)), play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecution.fromThread(ec))
            .thenApply(i -> ok("Got result: " + i));
}
```

Where doStuff only performs an entityManager.merge(), I get:

> [CompletionException: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is
>   closed!]

or

> [CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager
>   is closed]

When I use the code below to start the process above:

```
@Transactional
public Result mainMethod() {
    List<SomeObject> allObjects= dao.getAll();
    int size = allObjects.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        start(allObjects.get(i).getId());
    }
    return ok("Started");
}
```

Then the newly created threads(actors) get into an infinite loop when trying a database operation.

Thanks!

Complete stack trace:

> play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[CompletionException: org.hibernate.SessionException:
>   Session is closed!]]  at
>   play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
>     at
>   play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
>     at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
>     at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)    at
>   play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
>     at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
>     at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
>     at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
>     at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)    at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$P.accept(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:94)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$P.accept(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:89)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1595)
>     at
>   play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:56)
>     at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)    at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:405)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
>   org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!    at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1592)
>     ... 7 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.setCacheMode(SessionImpl.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1144)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
>     at daos.dao.get(dao.java:45)    at
>   controllers.DemoController.lambda$start$0(DemoController.java:195)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
>     ... 7 common frames omitted

**LE:**

Tried with:

```
ExecutionContext ec = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("akka.actor.db-context");
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> jpa.withTransaction("default", true, ()-> doStuff(dao.get(id))), play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecution.fromThread(ec))
                .thenApply(i -> ok("Got result: " + i));
```

And I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, so my simpler question: How do you make non web client blocking database operations using Play's Akka Actors? For example, start some update operation that sets some fields to certain values without having the client that sent the controller action waiting for the result(as it is not relevant to the user).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The *@Transactional* annotation is on the synchronous  method. I guess you need a transaction inside the async block.  You can use for jpa method *withTransaction* instead of the annotation. 
Its signature (from [Play java api](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/index.html))

```
/**
 * Run a block of code in a JPA transaction.
 *
 * @param name The persistence unit name
 * @param readOnly Is the transaction read-only?
 * @param block Block of code to execute
 * @param <T> type of result
 * @return code execution result
 */
public <T> T withTransaction(String name, boolean readOnly, Supplier<T> block);
```

It should be something like this:

1. Inject JPAApi in the controller:

   ```
   @Inject
   JPAApi jpa;
   ```
2. Implement async executor with call to jpa:

   ```
    jpa.withTransaction("default", true, ()->doStuff(dao.get(id)), play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecution.fromThread(ec))
       .thenApply(i -> ok("Got result: " + i)));
   ```

   Note the second argument *true* in the call to *withTransaction* is for readOnly operation (in your case).
3. Change the DAO class to use injected JPAAPi as well.

Comment: Hi, I can't find any "withTransaction" method with that signature.

Comment: I edited the answer - added the signature and link to API doc. I use this method in my project, just I do it synchronously. I prefer it to @Transactional annotation (don't forget to remove it !).

Comment: Have you removed both @Transactional annotations (there are 2 in your snippets). Probably JPA should be injected in a scope of the asynchronous method itself.

Comment: Yes, I did remove the annotations. I will try different injections and post the results here. Thank you.

Comment: I tried different ways, like sending the JPAApi as a parameter to the method, moving the method to another class and creating a new instances for every process + injecting the JPAApi, etc. but I still get the same error.

Comment: You can't send it as a method parameter. You should inject it in the thread of an executor. Inject like this: private  static final JPAApi jpa = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(JPAApi.class);. You can find more  about injection in Play at http://www.codepreference.com/2016/07/guice-dependency-injection-in-play.html.

Comment: I did some research and my code runs asynchronously as well. I guess that you should fix your DAO class (you omitted its code in your question). I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, I solved it after all using the code I just provided in the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using what @asch suggested:

Controller:

```
    @Inject
    private JPAApi jpa;
    [...]
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> jpa.withTransaction("default", false, ()-> doStuff(objectDAO.get(id))), play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecution.fromThread(ec))
                .thenApply(i -> ok("Got result: " + i));
```

And in the doStuff method class:

```
    private static final JPAApi jpaApi = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(JPAApi.class);
    [...]
    jpaApi.withTransaction(() -> {
        EntityManager em = jpaApi.em();
        em.merge(object);
    });
    [...]
```